# Consistency condition of multiplier system

Tags: number-theory, definition, modular-forms, modular-group

I have recently started reading modular forms and while reading I got to know that we are interested in holomorphic functions F on the upper half plane which satisfies the transformation law
$$
F(Mz)=v(M)j(M,z)^{k}F(z),\quad\forall z \in \mathbb{H},
$$
$M \in \gamma$ , where $\gamma$ is some subgroup of finite index in full modular group and $j(M,z)=(cz+d)$ with
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
After that I deduce that if $v$ is a multiplier associated with non-constant functions respecting the above transformation law then $v$ satisfies
$$
v(M_1M_2)j(M_1M_2,z)^k= v(M_1)v(M_2)j(M_1,M_2z)^kj(M_2,z)^k,
$$
for all $M_1,M_2 \in \gamma$ and $z\in \mathbb{H}$. Author defined this property as consistency condition of the multiplier v. My question is why its called consistency condition. What's consistency here of multiplier. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using your notation): let's examine
$$ f(M_1 M_2 z)$$
in two different ways. On the one hand,
$$ f(M_1 M_2 z) = v(M_1 M_2) j(M_1 M_2, z)^k f(z).$$
On the other hand, we have that
$$ f(M_1 M_2 z) = f\big( M_1 (M_2 z) \big)
= v(M_1) j(M_1, M_2 z)^k f(M_2 z)
= v(M_1) j(M_1, M_2 z)^k v(M_2) j(M_2, z)^k f(z),$$
and thus we must have that
$$ v(M_1 M_2) j(M_1 M_2, z)^k = v(M_1) v(M_2) j(M_1, M_2z)^k j(M_2, z)^k,$$
which is your consistency condition.

Comment: For the OP, this comparison of $f((M_1M_2)z)$ and $f(M_1(M_2z))$ is an "associativity" condition. It is a special case of the requirement in a group action that $g(hx) = (gh)x$, where $g, h$ belong to a group acting on a set containing the element $x$.

Comment: @david I know using the definition of group action we can deduce this which is called consistency condition. My question is why it's called consistency condition of the multiplier v.

Comment: @Vkay It's the *condition* to make things *consistent* with associativity of the matrix group action. Or the *condition* to make the two ways of calculating give *consistent* answers.